# ParseInt in an array

Tags: java, parseint

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NumAverage {

    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        //int a,b;
        int[] numbers = new int [10];

        Scanner numreader = new Scanner(System.in);

        try
        {
            System.out.println("Enter 10 num");
            for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
                numbers[i] = numreader.nextInt();
                //numbers[i] = Integer.parseInt(s)
            //for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
            //{
                //sum += numbers[i];
            //}
        }
        catch(NumberFormatException numfo)
        {
            System.out.println(numfo.getMessage() + "cannot be converted to integer");
        }
  }
}
```

How can i get the numbers I have being inputed from the keyboard into the array to be parseInt if the user tries to enter a string instead of an integer

Comment: How to get only the valid numbers and discard the strings?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NumAverage {

public static void main (String [] args)
{
    //int a,b;
    int[] numbers = new int [10];

    Scanner numreader = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter 10 num");
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        // Without the try and catch you get the appropriate exception,
        // NumberFormatException in this case
        String str = numreader.next();
        numbers[i] = Integer.parseInt(str);

        //try {
        //    numbers[i] = Integer.parseInt(numreader.next());
        //} catch(NumberFormatException e) {
        //    number[i] = 0; // or whatever you want
        //}
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Well this is working but I need it to have the option of throwing a NumberFormatException. So what should I move around?

Comment: Let me understand, if the number is malformed you want to throw a `NumberFormatException`? Or explain a little more.

Comment: For homewoek assigment question it is not ideal to present a ready code. some tipps and hints help more

Comment: Yes. I want the values to be read in as strings and then parseinted to convert it to an integer. and then it should throw a NumberFormatException.

Comment: if you need the exception, then do not catch it.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I would do for your case.

```
int[] numbers = new int[10];

Scanner numreader = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Enter 10 numbers");

// Get User Input
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    try {
        numbers[i] = Integer.parseInt((String) numreader.nextLine());
    } catch (NumberFormatException numFormatE) {
        System.out.println(numFormatE.getMessage() + "cannot be converted to integer");
        i = i - 1; // Restart current iteration.
    }
}
numreader.close();

// Loop through the number to get sum of the number.
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    sum += numbers[i];
}
System.out.println(sum);
```

**However, if you want to combine *sum* in the main loop, this should work as well:**

```
int[] numbers = new int[10];
int sum = 0;

Scanner numreader = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Enter 10 numbers");

// Get User Input
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    try {
        numbers[i] = Integer.parseInt((String) numreader.nextLine());
    } catch (NumberFormatException numFormatE) {
        System.out.println(numFormatE.getMessage() + "cannot be converted to integer");
        i = i - 1; // Restart current iteration.
    }
    sum += numbers[i]; // Add the number in loop
}
System.out.println(sum);
numreader.close();
```

**UPDATE: FIXED CODE FORMATTING**

Answer (score 0):

Integer.parse(String s) throws a NumberFormatException if s is not an integral number.
so surround the string to int conversion with a try-catch clause

Comment: So a try catch clause within a try catch clause?

Comment: instead of numreader.nextInt(), use numreader.nextLine() instead and do a parseInt on it.

Comment: Well this is working but I need it to have the option of throwing a NumberFormatException. So what should I move around?